# How to set volume to be at a specific value upon play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

It seems that when I play a song in the media player I've built, the volume is always on the maximum value (although the knob appears where I've set the value).

```js
//Volume control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100);

});
```

```html
<input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/cexeza/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It only displays the volume at the specified value; it does not _start_ the audio at that value when you press play.

Comment: What exactly the the steps that you do to reproduce the problem (Please describe as list, like: 1. Do this. 2. Do that etc.) So I could understand exactly the problem..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what you're trying to say. 

Basically, in the music player, when I click play on a track, I want the volume to be at only 50%. With the code I have now, it only **shows** the volume knob at 50%, but the song plays at 100% volume. I want to fix this so that every time I click on a new track, the volume is at 50%.

Comment: Are you using the **native** `audio` player or are you using a plugin?

Comment: Can you show me the code of you player? Or, even better, a live example of it?

Comment: HTML5 player. It'll take me too long to get the live example going. It's 2:32am here right now haha. The code is relatively long too. It's okay, i'll just keep trying tomorrow, i'll eventually get it! Appreciate the help!

Comment: OK, just let me know if `HTML5 player` mean `audio` tag or a plugin (try to post the html code.

Comment: Okay here is the HTML and JS

http://pastebin.com/mq7YMiCq

Comment: Again, works for me: http://output.jsbin.com/zocava. Never mind, sleep well ;)